# Event working perfectly in Chrome, but not in Firefox Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have implemented a simple event in Vue.js that hides a div when the user clicks on them and displays them again when enter is pressed:

```
<div class="room" v-show=show.room  @click='toggle = !toggle'>

          </div>
```

below I have divs that are shown using the v-show directive:

```
<div v-show="toggle" :class="[{clickedButton: isSelected}]" class="desk-area" @click="selected = workSpace; draw(workSpace);isSelected = !isSelected">
           <img :class="[{clickedImage: isSelected}]" class="seat-icon" alt="desk icon" src="/svg/icons/blue-seat.svg">
           <span class="desk-text">desks area</span>
          </div>
```

the toggle boolean is being kept in data:

```
 data: () => ({
    toggle: true,
  }),
```

I have a method that toggles it:

```
toggleMethod() {
      this.toggle = true;
    },
```

and I am attaching the keyup event in the created lifecycle hook:

```
created: function () {
   document.addEventListener('keyup', this.toggleMethod)
  },
```

When the user clicks on the div in Chrome it hides, when he presses Enter it shows, but in Firefox it doesn't hide and show, what can be done to make it work for firefox as well?

Comment: What exactly does not work? Do you have any trace of what's going on in Developer Tools(F12)?

Comment: Can you please combine your code in JSFiddle and share it here?

Comment: No, it doesn't hide the icons and it seems that the entire event does not work, I can;t even do a simple alert

Comment: `but not in Firefox, why?` because Firefox is not Chrome and there are differences, but as you've failed to provide any detail of the problem, it's hard to speculate at a solution - I'd start with some debugging - `console.log` in various places in your code for a start

Comment: If you want to use native events in Vue it is recommended you use the `.native` modifier. `@click.native="expression"`. Without a proper [mcve] it is hard to speculate on what the problem might be in your case.